# Mysql: only display most fitting LIKE request

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i try to make a "live-search".

**What I want**

Searchstring 1: "%ete%"

Searchstring 2: "%er%"

```
| City   | Land    | Artist |
-----------------------------
| Köln   | Germany | Peter  |
| Bonn   | Germany | Bernd  |
| Berlin | Germany | Karl   |
-----------------------------
```

Result 1: Peter

Result 2: Germany *AND* Berlin *AND* Peter *AND* BERND

i have a jquery keyup event, a ajax and this php/mysql script:

```
$query=$_POST['value'];

$result='<ul class="db_s_answer">';
$abfrage = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM imgdb WHERE artist LIKE '%".$query."%' OR ort LIKE '%".$query."%' LIMIT 5");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($abfrage)) {

    $ergebnis=preg_replace("/".$query."/i","<b>$0</b>",HERE THE MOST FITTING VARIABLE,-1);
    $result.='<li><div><p>'.$ergebnis.'</p></div></li>';

}

$result.='</ul>';
```

Comment: **Warning** your code is vulnerable to [sql injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION` :

```
"SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT artist FROM imgdb WHERE artist LIKE '%".$query."%'
    UNION
    SELECT ort FROM imgdb WHERE ort LIKE '%".$query."%' 
) LIMIT 5"
```